# How to connect to PostgreSQL on the host from the minikube pod?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, quarkus, minikube

I have written a quarkus application that uses PostgreSQL, made a docker image, and tested the application using `host.docker.internal` as a host to connect to the PostgreSQL instance.

After that, I installed `minikube v1.30.1 (MacOS)`. My URL for connection is `jdbc:postgresql://host.minikube.internal:5432/my_db`, but when the application is starting I see the next line in the log:

`Connection to host.minikube.internal:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

If I enter `nc -vz host.minikube.internal 5432` in `minikube ssh` I am getting: `Connection to host.minikube.internal 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!`.

P.S. I have just one pod object (maybe I should add another object to put traffic to my PostgreSQL instance).

Comment: I'd expect your application to have a single Deployment.  Can you run the database in a StatefulSet inside the cluster?  (Maybe using a prepackaged Helm chart?)  Are there any unusual networking settings in your Pod spec?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, I have the single deployment. I do not want to use PostgreSQL inside the cluster. I did not do any networking settings in my Pod spec.